# How to make different length list to a single dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Structure of my data is in this form.

data1:

```
['https://www.fullstackpython.com/',
 ['https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-contents.html',
  'https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog.html'],
 [['Introduction',
   'Development Environments',
   'Web Development ',
   'Web App Deployment',
   'Data',
   ''],
  ['5 Years of Full Stack Python',
   'GitPython and New Git Tutorials ',
   'First Steps with GitPython']],
 [[0.0,
   0.0,
   0.25,
   0.29,
   0.25,
   0.25],
  [0.0, 1.0, 0.19]]]
```

How to make different length list to a single Data frame in python? 
I have tried with pandas `DataFrame` .But it wont work since each list in `data1` has different length. Same problem for the `zip` function also. 
I am expecting this structure for the list of data, not necessary as a table ,but as a data frame. I am trying some general approach ,so that any similar information can be fed into this format.

[image: expecting this structure for the list of datas]

Comment: posting what you've tried may help provide more context. for example, have you tried using the python `zip` function?

Comment: is `data1` your input? or what you want to obtain? (and for each case, what is the other one?)

Comment: I have tried with zip.I have made the necessary edits in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source data format is consistent with the example, the "rows" could be looped over in the following way, and then converted to a DataFrame.

```
In [1]: src = ['https://www.fullstackpython.com/',
   ...:  ['https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-contents.html',
   ...:   'https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog.html'],
   ...:  [['Introduction', 'Development Environments', 'Web Development ',
   ...:    'Web App Deployment', 'Data', ''],
   ...:   ['5 Years of Full Stack Python',
   ...:    'GitPython and New Git Tutorials ',
   ...:    'First Steps with GitPython']],
   ...:  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.29, 0.25, 0.25],
   ...:   [0.0, 1.0, 0.19]]]

In [2]: site, pages, nested_titles, nested_values = src

In [3]: data = []
   ...: for page, titles, values in zip(pages, nested_titles, nested_values):
   ...:     for title, value in zip(titles, values):
   ...:         data.append((site, page, title, value))
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Site', 'Page', 'Title', 'Value'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
                               Site                                               Page                             Title  Value
0  https://www.fullstackpython.com/  https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-conte...                      Introduction   0.00
1  https://www.fullstackpython.com/  https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-conte...          Development Environments   0.00
2  https://www.fullstackpython.com/  https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-conte...                  Web Development    0.25
3  https://www.fullstackpython.com/  https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-conte...                Web App Deployment   0.29
4  https://www.fullstackpython.com/  https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-conte...                              Data   0.25
5  https://www.fullstackpython.com/  https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-conte...                                     0.25
6  https://www.fullstackpython.com/          https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog.html      5 Years of Full Stack Python   0.00
7  https://www.fullstackpython.com/          https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog.html  GitPython and New Git Tutorials    1.00
8  https://www.fullstackpython.com/          https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog.html        First Steps with GitPython   0.19
```

Comment: For displaying the data frame completely on the screen i have used 'pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  ' comment. But still     'Site  \' ,'Page  \' is there. df[7:8] appears in 3 lines. Why its not displayed at a single structure?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're seeing (feel free to open a new question if needed), but also check the max_rows and max_colwidth display settings, or try df.to_string() to bypass the display settings